# How to concatenate variable and string that contains () in php

Tags: php, string-concatenation

I want to output the string:

```
Mango Meals (April Song)
```

But I'm getting the string:

```
"Mango Meals (April Song)"
```

How do I concatenate the string and variable in php properly?

**HTML**

```
$title = $row[ 'title'];
$credit = $row[ 'credit' ];
print('<div class = "album_title"> "'.$title.' ('.$credit.')" </div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the quotes within the string.

```
print('<div class = "album_title">'.$title.' ('.$credit.')</div>');
//                              --^--                   --^--
```

Answer (score 0):

using [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
echo sprintf('<div class = "album_title"> %s (%s)" </div>', $title, $credit);
```

this would be simpler than escaping quotes or concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

Change like this

```
echo '<div class ="album_title">'.$title.'('.$credit.')'.'</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have  the double " quote  inside the (html text) string
try without it

```
print('<div class = "album_title"> '.$title.' ('.$credit.') </div>');
```